# Django isn't serving static files

Tags: python, django, web, static, resources

I'm working with an existing (and previously functional) Django site. We recently upgraded from Django 1.8.13 to 1.10 and our WSGI is Gunicorn. It works fine when hosted from my development machine, but when deployed, all static resources (on the admin and the main site) yield 404's with the message, `Directory indexes are not allowed here.`

Our `settings.py` contains the following:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    ...
)

DEBUG = True
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static'),
)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static_resources')
```

The directory structure looks like this:

```
/my-project-name
    /my-project-name
        server.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
    ...
    /static
    /static_resources
    manage.py
```

Comment: What WSGI you are using?

Comment: We're using Gunicorn

Comment: Gunicorn will not handle static files for you, did you guys also use nginx for static files?

Comment: Not sure. I'm new to the project, I just know we haven't changed anything outside of the python code and it worked before

Comment: How you deploy your project, Docker or what? Be sure nginx configure is correct.

Comment: FTP and a reboot over ssh

Comment: Please show us about your directory tree.

Comment: I've updated the question with the directory structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was very subtle. When I upgraded Django to 1.9 and ran the server, it gave the following warning:

`?: (urls.W001) Your URL pattern '^static/(?P<path>.*)$' uses include with a regex ending with a '$'. Remove the dollar from the regex to avoid problems including URLs.`

In `urls.py`, my `urlpatterns` list contained:

```
url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
    'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT,
}),
```

I changed it to:

```
url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)/', 'django.views.static.serve', {
    'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT,
}),
```

This eliminated the warning but caused static resources to stop loading.
It needed to be:

```
url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)', 'django.views.static.serve', {
    'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT,
}),
```

It's still a mystery to me why this worked on my dev machine (a Macbook), as well as another on the team's dev machine (a windows laptop), but not on our Linux server. But, it works now, so I'm done trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Django does not serve static files in production mode (DEBUG=False). On a production deployment that's the job of the webserver. To resolve the problem:

- run `python manage.py collectstatic`
- in your web server configuration point the `/static` folder to the static folder of Django

Don't just turn DEBUG on, it would be dangerous!

Comment: This is in a dev environment, and we have `DEBUG = True`. I'll add that to the code in the original question.

Comment: To clarify, we're deploying from the dev machine to a server, but it's a server intended for testing, so it's still safe to use `DEBUG = True`

Answer (score 0):

Try to change os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, '../static') to os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static') and STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, '../static_resources') to STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static_resources'). It will solve your problem.

Comment: That doesn't solve it because neither of those would be real directories in our project structure

Comment: Just to make sure, I changed PROJECT_DIR so it would point to the outer project folder instead of the settings.py folder (which to fair makes more sense), and removed the "../"'s. Still nothing.